# Getting change id's of depending changes from gerrit rest or ssh api?

Tags: gerrit

Gerrit allows associated external changes into a single change request via "Depends-On" on the commit message. However, by the looks of it, rest api does not expose these dependencies.

I can ofcourse get the commit message and then parse it, and then get change request for this external change.

Anyone know if there would be a bit more streamlined option to archive the same ?

Comment: Did you find out a way to list all the dependencies?

Comment: Nope .. Ended up building some parsing mechanism on top of parsing commit messages..

Comment: Can you share some details on how you build the solution? I am planning to use depends-on for cross repo dependencies management.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the related changes using REST API:

> 'GET /changes/{change-id}/revisions/{revision-id}/related'
>
> Retrieves related changes of a revision. Related changes are changes
>   that either depend on, or are dependencies of the revision.
>
> Request   GET
>   /changes/gerrit~master~I5e4fc08ce34d33c090c9e0bf320de1b17309f774/revisions/b1cb4caa6be46d12b94c25aa68aebabcbb3f53fe/related
>   HTTP/1.0

See more info in the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#get-related-changes)

Comment: if the main change-id is "top level" change, and it has multiple "Depends-On" fields in the commit message, it (the api you suggested) does not contain the dependencies.